# Rails simple_fields_for with array not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form of a user and a user has many trips (a trip belongs to one user only). When editing the user, i also want to be able to edit the number of people attending the trip. the thing is i only want to show trips that lay in the future. for that i have a method def future_trips inside my user model.

now, i can display the edit page of the user just fine, but it doesn't show the trips. this is my view (in haml):

```
- simple_form_for model do |f|
  = f.input :username, disabled: true
# ... some more stuff...

  %hr/
  .table-container
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th= 'Trip name'
          %th= 'Amount people'
      %tbody
        %p= model.future_trips.size # shows 2
        #THIS DOES NOT WORK:
        - f.simple_fields_for model.future_trips do |form|
          %tr
            %td= 'hello'
            %td= form.input :attendees
```

in my `user.rb` model i put `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `has_many :trips` and in my `trips.rb` model I have `belongs_to :user`.

Why is it not working? I thought `simple_fields_for` worked with an array.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake... I typed

```
- f.simple_fields_for model.future_trips do |form|
```

but the correct way would be

```
= f.simple_fields_for :trips, model.future_trips do |form|
```

So i used `-` instead of `=` and forgot `:trips`. that was the problem